# How to make expression-dependent replacements?

Tags: replacement, pattern-matching

Consider as a toy example that I want a replacement
which acts on

```
{x,1,2,3}
```

by replacing $x$ with the length of the list itself. In this example this should output

> {4,1,2,3}

So I want a code that looks like

```
{x,1,2,3}/.{x->Length[???]}
```

where "???" should indicate the expression on which I am doing the replacement.
Is there a way to do this or an easy alternative ?

Comment: {x, 1, 2, 3} /. x1 : {x, x2__} :> {Length[x1], x2}

Answer (score 6):

You can make a named pattern for the entire list using the `:` operator:

```
{x, 1, 2, 3} /. list : {x, rest___} :> {Length[list], rest}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
a = {x, 1, 2, 3};
```

Using `SubsetReplace` (new in 12.1)

```
SubsetReplace[a, {x} :> Length[a]]
```

Using `ReplaceAt` (new in 13.1)

```
ReplaceAt[a, _ :> Length[a], 1]
```

Both produce

> {4, 1, 2, 3}

Answer (score 3):

If you can match on the whole expression, you can do this:

```
{x, 1, 2, 3} /. l : {x, rest___} :> {Length[l], rest}
```

or

```
{x, 1, 2, 3} /. l : {x, ___} :> ReplacePart[l, 1 -> Length[l]]
```

or

```
{x, 1, 2, 3} /. {x, rest___} :> {1 + Length[{rest}], rest}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
#/.x:>Length[#]&[{x,1,2,3}]

(* {4,1,2,3} *)
```

Or

```
Replace[#, x:> Length[#],1]&[{x,1,2,3}]

(* {4,1,2,3} *)
```